# reliable scale aware and lightweight object tracking on real life video stream

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to make a python script which tracks people on live video stream. My script uses pose detector from mediapipe solutions and face-recognition module which does some dlib magic under the hood.

Currently I locate faces, and check for overlaps with body bbox and group them in such fashion, however face-recognition module is slow, and I'm trying to work my way around it. In particular, I try to only detect face every 500th frame, and in between use mean-shift algorithm provided by opencv-python to adjust position of face.

This is not very reliable, even when I introduced certain threshold of dx and dy which when exceeded forces face-recognition to take over again. My guess is that lighting and scale cause problems, so I look for alternative solution.